# Test object equality in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, object, comparison, coffeescript, equality

Is there a simple way to test equality of objects in CoffeeScript?

Or more correctly - test if the properties of two objects are identical.

With these objects:

```
obj1 =
  name: "John Doe"
  age: "3.14"

obj2 =
  name: "John Doe"
  age: "3.14"
```

This evaluates false, as expected:

```
obj1 == obj2
```

For now I'm using [Underscore's isEqual](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual)

Comment: What's wrong with `_.isEqual`? You need to perform _some_ sort of deep equality.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the Underscore method but I'd be interested in a short-hand language feature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope. CoffeeScript doesn't provide this as a language feature, so using a library like Underscore.js is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old standby:

```
JSON.stringify(obj1) == JSON.stringify(obj2)
```

Which will do the job - but may be too inefficient for some jobs.

You could also turn your arbitrary objects into a class and provide an equals method on the class.

```
class Person
  constructor: (@name, @age) ->
  
  equals: (other) -> @name == other.name && @age == other.age
```